# Keep Navbar on Top of Website Content

Tags: jquery, css

I am having problems with the navbar on my site. THe navbar is built using jquery and css  and has replaced the wordpress navbar on my website.

Website is http://renocharlton.com/

I am aware that some of the content is flash - however the navbar is going under the images on the page.

Can any one suggest a solution to the issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: They didn't tell you which element, so I'm going to make it easy for you. `.dropmenu  li`. add `z-index:1000;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use:

```
ul.dropmenu {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

Comment: Thanks - this has worked - and I'm sure the other answers on here are just as good. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Probably z-index of overlapping images is too high. Try to set it to -10

Answer (score 0):

Set the `z-index` of the menus to a fairly high value, such as `10000`.

Alternatively, move the markup for the menus to the end of the page, although that might not be easy depending on your layout.

Answer (score 0):

define in your css as like this 
your css

```
.dropmenu li > ul, .dropmenu li > div{
z-index:9;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just update your CSS and set the **`z-index`** value.